# Assigning value to 2 d dynamic array in C++, using C++ shell, console doesn't print out anything

Tags: c++

i am really new to C++ programming. I am trying to write a program that get series of grade input from user then create a histogram using dynamic 2 D array and store the grade with its corresponding replications. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void sortGradeBubble(vector<int> &);
int countDiffNumber(vector<int>, int);
int main() {
    int grade = 0;
    bool validGrade = true;
    vector<int> grades;
    // get grades from users
    do {
        grades.clear();
            if (!validGrade) {
                cout << "one of the Grade is less than 0 or greater than 100 please enter again";
            }
        cout << "Please input the grade (negative value to exit, grade must be from 0 to 100): ";
        while (grade != -1) {
            cin >> grade;
            if (grade < -1 || grade > 100) {
                validGrade = false;
                grade = -1;
            } else if (grade != -1){
                cin.ignore();
                grades.push_back(grade);
            }
        };
    } while (!validGrade);
    //sort the grades in accending order
    sortGradeBubble(grades);
    int size = grades.size();
    //get number of how many different grade in the array
    int diffNumber = countDiffNumber(grades, size);
    //initial empty histogram
    int** histogram;
    histogram = new int*[diffNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < diffNumber; i += 1){
        histogram[i] = new int[2];
        };
    //Assigning grade and replicates to the histogram
    int county = 0;//counter increment each time current grade  different than the next grade in the array
    int replicates = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
        if (grades[i] != grades[i + 1]) {
            histogram[county][0] = grades[i];
            histogram[county][1] = replicates;
            county += 1;
            replicates = 1;
        } else {
            replicates += 1;
        }; 
    };
    //Print the result to screen
    for (int i = 0; i < diffNumber; i += 1){
        cout << "Number " << histogram[i][0] << " :" << histogram[i][1] << "\n";
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < diffNumber; i +=1){
            delete[] histogram[i];
            }
            delete[] histogram;
    return 0;
}
void sortGradeBubble(vector<int> &grades) {
    int size;
    size = grades.size();
    bool swap;
    int temp;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
        {
            if (grades[count] > grades[count + 1])
            {
                temp = grades[count];
                grades[count] = grades[count + 1];
                grades[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}
int countDiffNumber(vector<int> grades, int size) {
    int counter = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
        if (grades[i] != grades[i + 1]) {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

it seems like the problem is in the assigning values progress of the 2D Array:

```
//Assigning grade and replicates to the histogram
        int county = 0;
        int replicates = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1) {
            if (grades[i] != grades[i + 1]) {
                histogram[county][0] = grades[i];
                histogram[county][1] = replicates;
                county += 1;
                replicates = 1;
            } else {
                replicates += 1;
            }; 
        };
```

.I tried to exclude the "county+=1" line and everything works fine again. Hope someone can help me with this matter

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your code, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables as they are changed, by your code, what observations did you make? The answer to your question is, really, learn how to use a debugger. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions.

Comment: In case no one has told you this before, please look at our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the one on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your code "works fine" without the `county+=1` line, then what's the problem? Pare the code down to the simplest version that produces the error, then post that.

Comment: Can you explain how your code intends to save the value of the very last histogram, when the histogram is only saved when the sorted values, that go into histogram change?

Comment: By fine i meant the console log onto to the screen my test output which is the for loop that i put at the very end of the code. I stated that “county+=1” which means the problem is that line. I am using c++ Shell to compile, normally there would be error but this time after i enter the grades and enter (with -1 at the end of the series), the program just return 0, stop running. No sign of error at all. My english is not perfect, sorry about the misunderstanding @Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mistake appears at least twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i += 1) {
  if (array[i] != array[i + 1]) {
    ...
```

If the array has five elements, the first is `array[0]` and the last is `array[4]`. This loop compares `array[0]` to `array[1]`, `array[1]` to `array[2]`,... and `array[4]` to `array[5]`. But there is no `array[5]`. When you read or write past the end of a structure, you cause Undefined Behavior.

The bug vanishes when you remove `county+=1;`, but that is an illusion. That line is irrelevant, but when you remove it the bug falls silent. It is undefined behavior, it can behave in strange ways.

Many programmers say "arrays are crude and obsolete. Do not study them, it is a waste of time. Study more sophisticated containers, like `std::vector`." I say "arrays are simple and fundamental, and so is this mistake. If you do not learn this, then you will continue to make the mistake with more complex structures. Learn arrays, then advance to more sophisticated containers."